# Chris Pine Learn to Program Ruby Ch 8: alphabetize your array

Tags: ruby, sorting

Getting stuck on chapter 8:

Type as many words as we want
One word per line, continuing until we just press Enter on an empty line
Repeats the words back to us in alphabetical order. 
Use 'sort'

So, here's what I got to, but I'm having funny issues with not getting the first word to push into the array [among other things]

```
# alphabetting

puts 'Tell us some of your favorite things!'

# create an array
words = []

while gets.chomp != ''
  words.push gets.chomp
  words.sort
    puts words 
end
```

Did this and it works now... Do I have to have "thing" in there though? Seems naughty to assign within a 'while' loop.

```
puts 'Tell us some of your favorite things!'

words = []
puts words

while (thing = gets.chomp) != ''
  words.push thing
end

puts words.sort
```

Comment: Did you try doing "puts words" prior to the sort? That or try storing gets.chomp in a variable and then doing words.push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `gets` call is not referred to by anything, and is thrown out. It is not just the first word, but every other word that is going to be thrown out. The output routine should also be outside of the loop. A fix is:

```
words = []
while word = gets.chomp and not word.empty?
  words.push(word)
end
puts words.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
puts 'Tell us some of your favorite things!'

words = []
while line = STDIN.gets
  line = line.chomp
  break if line.empty?
  words << line.chomp
end

words = words.sort

words.each {|word| puts word }
```

Comment: I'm supposed to be using the [] in here, so I'm sure that works, but it's kinda ten steps beyond the solution I'm meant to be reaching!